# How can I add clickable numbers to my slides?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is based off of my previous question: [How can I get this code to continuously loop through the items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781387/how-can-i-get-this-code-to-continuously-loop-through-the-items)

Now I want to have numbers corresponding to each slide and have them clickable so you can go to that slide.

Here's a link to my jsfiddle on what I have tried: http://jsfiddle.net/allisonc/xu9ym/

HTML:

```
<div id="design-tips">
    <div id="design-tips-title">Design tips</div>
    <div id="design-tips-content"></div>
    <div id="design-tips-controls"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
xmlstr = "<photo><item>To add a photo to your project,drag the photo from the list to the opening.</item><item>You can position your photo in the opening by dragging...</item><item>...and you can also edit the photo by double-clicking on it!</item></photo>"

xml = $.parseXML(xmlstr)
var items = 0;
var control = '';

var tips = $('item', xml).get().map(function(item){
    items++;
    if(items==1) control = control + '<a href="#" class="selected" rel="'+items+'">'+items+'</a>';
    else control = control + '<a href="#" rel="'+items+'">'+items+'</a>';
    return $(item).text();
});
console.log(tips);
$('#design-tips-controls').html(control);  
var currentIndex = 0;

function looper() {
    if(currentIndex>=tips.length) {
        currentIndex = 0;
    }
    $('#design-tips-content').html(tips[currentIndex])   
    currentIndex++;
}
looper();
setInterval(looper, 5000);

$('#design-tips-controls a').on('click', function()
{
    $('#design-tips-content').html(tips[$(this).attr('rel')]);   
});
```

Comment: I found this script called AwesomeSlider that works for me

Comment: First: learn to write your code. Too much confusion anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Watta confusion! 
I suggest you to give a class attribute to your div, in this way:

```
<div id="design-tips">
    <div id="design-tips-title" class="slide">Design tips</div>
    <div id="design-tips-content" class="slide"></div>
    <div id="design-tips-controls" class="slide"></div>
</div>
```

In this way you can:

```
$('.slide').on('click', foo);

var foo = function() {
  console.log("how I am", $(this));
  /* your code */
}
```

To add clickable number:

```
$('.slide').each(function (i) {
    $(this).click(function () {
       /* add here your href linked to i-number */
    });
});
```